# Show only a specific part of html response in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get tracking information from amazon using provided url
https://www.amazon.co.uk/progress-tracker/package/ref=pe_3187911_189395841_TE_typ?_encoding=UTF8&from=gp&itemId=&orderId=203-2171364-3066749&packageIndex=0&shipmentId=23796758607302

I am getting response using `file_get_contents()` function in php,
what I want is to show only that part of the response which contains the tracking information as an output of my php script and eliminate/hide all the unnecessary content from `file_get_contents()` response.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do what you're looking for is use DomDocument to filter out the json data in the source (`$file`) and then use a recursive function to get the elements you need.

You can set the elements you need using an array, `$filter`. In this example we've taken a sample of some of the available data, i.e. :

```
$filter = [
'orderId', 'shortStatus', 'promiseMessage',
'lastTransitionPercentComplete', 'lastReachedMilestone', 'shipmentId',
];
```

The code

```
<?php

$filename = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/progress-tracker/package/ref=pe_3187911_189395841_TE_typ?_encoding=UTF8&from=gp&itemId=&orderId=203-2171364-3066749&packageIndex=0&shipmentId=23796758607302';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);

$trackingData = []; // store for order tracking data
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($file);
foreach ($html->getElementsByTagName('script') as $a) {
    $data = $a->textContent;
    if (stripos($data, 'shortStatus') !== false) {
        $trackingData = json_decode($data, true);
        break;
    }
}

// set the items we need
$filter = [
    'orderId', 'shortStatus', 'promiseMessage',
    'lastTransitionPercentComplete', 'lastReachedMilestone', 'shipmentId',
];
// invoke recursive function to pick up the data items specified in $filter
$result = getTrackingData($filter, $trackingData);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

function getTrackingData(array $filter, array $data, array &$result = []) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            getTrackingData($filter, $value, $result);
        } else {
            foreach($filter as $item) {
                if($item === $key) {
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [orderId] => 203-2171364-3066749
    [shortStatus] => IN_TRANSIT
    [promiseMessage] => Arriving tomorrow by 9 PM
    [lastTransitionPercentComplete] => 92
    [lastReachedMilestone] => SHIPPED
    [shipmentId] => 23796758607302
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$filename = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/progress-tracker/package/ref=pe_3187911_189395841_TE_typ?_encoding=UTF8&from=gp&itemId=&orderId=203-2171364-3066749&packageIndex=0&shipmentId=23796758607302';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($file);
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('span') as $a) {
    $property=$a->getAttribute('id');
    if (strpos($property , "primaryStatus"))
        print_r($property);             

}
?>
```

It should show "Arriving tomorrow by 9 PM" status.

Comment: Have you tested this? This just prints the `id`. Besides, I think OP wants all of the tracking information, not just the current status.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to show timeline as well like Ordered, Dispatched today, Out for delivery, Arriving tomorrow ?

Comment: you can do this using getElementsByTagName and getAttribute functions. read the source code of amazon page